# Flutter Client, Python server WebSocket

Tags: python, flutter, dart, sockets, websocket

I am trying to making a program with a login system. I make the program with flutter and I made the server in python but when I try to sent a message to server it doesn't come but it can connect anyone know why this happens??

```
void sendData() {
  final channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('ws://localhost:4609'));
  channel.sink.add('FU');
  channel.sink.close(status.goingAway);
}
```

sending message to server

I try to sent message to python server in flutter
I except to send the message to server